# How to display Qframe as actual size in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is My program. My Requirement: Display frame as mentioned size. But in my code its occupies the entire area. How to resolve it?

```
import sys
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class FrameExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame Example")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1500,900)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.resize(300, 300)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color:skyblue")

        self.frame1 = QFrame()
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QRect(10,10,600,600))
        self.frame1.resize(600,600)
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightgreen")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    countrywin =FrameExample()

    countrywin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `resize()` you are managing the size of the widget but after setting the layouts it will handle the size. One possible solution is to use `setFixedSize()`:

```py
class FrameExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1500, 900)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color:skyblue")

        self.frame1 = QFrame()
        self.frame1.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightgreen")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame1)
```

Comment: Its work, But if window changes its not grow, I Need with grow and shrink

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Your request was clear: "Display frame as mentioned size". If you have other requirements then create a new post where you detail what you want.